# PyQGIS refresh layer tree programmatically

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, filter, layertree

When programmatically applying a subset string to a vector layer (here: `ax_flurstueck` with object count 34265)

[image]

via

```
l = iface.activeLayer()
l.setSubsetString('gemarkungsnummer in ('2760','2765','2771','2780','2786','2800','2811','2817','2836')')
```

the map canvas refreshes automatically, but not the object count in the layer tree (displays still 34265 objects):

[image]

When moving the main window around or changing the width of the layer tree or something like that, the layer tree refreshes (21581 objects).

[image]

The question is, how to achieve this programmatically? I did not find something like:

QgsLayerTreeView.refesh()

in analogy to refreshing the map canvas. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a quick response but this code work perfectly,and you can refresh featurecount on QgsLayerTreeView.

**1:Option**

```
l = iface.activeLayer()
l.setSubsetString('gemarkungsnummer in ('2760','2765','2771','2780','2786','2800','2811','2817','2836')')
qgisTView = qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView()
actions=qgisTView.defaultActions ()
actions.showFeatureCount ()
actions.showFeatureCount ()
```

**2: Option**

Replicate core code in Python.

```
iface=qgis.utils.iface
l = iface.activeLayer()
l.setSubsetString('gemarkungsnummer in ('2760','2765','2771','2780','2786','2800','2811','2817','2836')')

mView= iface.layerTreeView()
node = iface.layerTreeView().currentNode()
nodeslist=mView.selectedLayerNodes()
newValue = node.customProperty("showFeatureCount", 0 ) 
for value in nodeslist:
    value.setCustomProperty("showFeatureCount", int(newValue));
```

Comment: Great job +1, but just one question (or two respectivly): 1. How did you figure out that `actions.showFeatureCount()` is required twice and 2. Why is that so? I tested this with only one `actions.showFeatureCount()` and this does not work, my first thought was that this was some 'careless mistake' due to the late evening time you wrote the answer... :-)

Comment: Closer looked at, stupid question of mine. The first `actions.showFeatureCount()` uncheckes the 'show feature count' checkbox, the second checkes it again ...

Comment: you can replicate the core code,too:  https://qgis.org/api/qgslayertreeviewdefaultactions_8cpp_source.html , line 160